# How to organize references for plugin DLLs in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, plugins

I'm working on an application that loads in plugins through `Assembly.Load`. I want to make sure plugins DLLs don't contain more compiled code then they need. Currently I've got 2 projects:

- Application
- MyPlugin

MyPlugin has a class implementing `IPlugin` from the Application project, and references the project to do so.
Is this the correct way to do it or should I put IPlugin (along with interfaces for anything plugins need access to) in a separate project, or is there some other better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely create a new project containing only the contracts (interfaces) which could be referenced by the plugin projects. Besides, take a look at [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

this is a great way to create a plugin architecture in .NET. And it also is a part of .NET.

Comment: Why would a separate project with only contracts be better? I know it's a thing I could do but I don't know why I would do it. Also I've made an attempt at using MEF2 but have ran into nothing but headaches and lacking documentation.

Comment: well if you keep the interfaces within your "Application" project, all plugins would know too much about the consuming application (could even try to use what is public) - to much coupling. What if you would like to build a cool new Application and reuse those plugins? Would you really want the new application to reference the old one? Your goal is to extend, it is not important how the host application works (from plugin's point of view) as long as you satisfy the contracts. Tink about extending Visual Studio...Those extensions do not reference Visual Studio itself...

Comment: We are using MEF in conjunction with Prism on my current project and we are happy with it. The documentation is a bit scarce but it is definitely worth spending some time getting to know MEF and its power

Comment: Hm, while reusing these plugins in a different project doesn't make much sense in this situation, it would make sense for the API to stay the same across versions while the application itself could change. Could add the detail about reusing plugins across applications and versions to the answer? I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: If you have a separate contracts dll, you kind of decouple the providers of the functionality(plugins) from the consumers(actual apps). This contracts dll can be shared with other devs, who could develop their plugins without even knowing what your app looks like. A whole new app or just a new version of it with a different UI could be build This new app would just reference this contracts dll and utilize the plugins in an appropriate way.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is the versioning of you contracts dll. 
If you change the contract you should consider both sides (provider and consumer) because both depend on it.
In this case you might wanna offer different versions of you contracts dll: one for the old apps and another one for the new apps (using the changed version of contracts dll).
In this way folks would write plugins using the version of you contracts dll which the consuming app can deal with.

Comment: Version management could be done with Nuget for example if you decide to distribute the contract dll like a Nuget package.
I hope I got your question right :)